# Html2canvas vs jspdf can't export svg in PDF file

Tags: reactjs, jspdf, html2canvas

I use html2canvas vs jsPDF in my Reactjs project and I had a required that's export a DOM node to PDF file. When I exported, HTML and CSS was keeped just SVG can't. I dont know why. Have another package on client can help me? Thank for your attetion.
Here is my code to export

```
const filename = 'TyVan.pdf';
    html2canvas(document.querySelector('#buivanty'),{scale: quality}).then(canvas => {
        let pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'mm', 'a4', true)

        pdf.addImage(canvas.toDataURL('image/png', 1.0), 'png', 10, 10, 180, 150);
        pdf.save(filename);
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve it by doing post processing using onClone option

```
const options = {
  scale: 1,
  foreignObjectRendering: true,
  onclone: (element) => {
    const svgElements: any[] = element.body.getElementsByTagName('svg');
    Array.from(svgElements).forEach((svgElement) => {
        const bBox: any = svgElement.getBBox();
        svgElement.setAttribute('width', bBox.width);
        svgElement.setAttribute('height', bBox.height);
    });
  },
};

  html2canvas(<HTMLScriptElement>document.querySelector('.main-container'), options).then(canvas => {
      this.clipImage = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
  });
```

Comment: Can I custom width and height of svg? :))). This code was great. just had a problems about svg size :)) Thank you very much